# An adjective or a noun?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

In the collocation "baby girl" is "baby" an adjective or a noun?

Comment: Two days ago, we just had the question on noun adjective. This is a dupl. Anat, please research previous questions.

Answer (score 3):

The answer would depend on context, but in most cases I think it is safe to assume *baby* is an *[attributive noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/when-can-a-noun-be-used-attributively)* (or *noun adjunct*)— a noun which modifies another noun.

See also *[When can a noun be used attributively?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/when-can-a-noun-be-used-attributively)*.

Comment: How about 'a baby kitten'? Or even 'a baby oven' ?

Comment: I can't think of a situation in which it would be an adjective. It always stays a nominal modifier.

Comment: Google claims it can: ... **baby** adjective
1.
comparatively small or immature of its kind. AHD goes further: **baby** adj. bab·i·er, bab·i·est
1. Of or having to do with a baby.
2. Infantile or childish.
3. Small in comparison with others of the same kind: baby vegetables.