# Nouns as adjectives question

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, phrase-usage, writing

I have a question regarding this sentence

> Yesterday, I went to the mall to buy **child clothing/clothes** for my baby.

Is it wrong to write it this way? Or should it be *children*? Because I always see this phrase "Baby Clothing" on every commercial/advertisement.

I looked up the internet, but the majority use "Children Clothing", but I don't know why 'child clothing' is wrong.

Comment: Those are nouns used as attributes of other nouns, not as adjectives. And I can't believe anyone says "children clothing". That sounds completely unnatural. It’s either "children’s clothing" or else "child clothing".

Comment: You have come across an idiosyncrasy of the English language here.  It is often impossible to predict idiomaticity on the basis of known patterns. _Baby clothing_, using the singular-form attributive noun, is idiomatic. But _children clothing_ isn't. Traditionally, _children's clothing_, but increasingly _childrens clothing_, is the correct choice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Shame on you and all your childrens too.

Comment: @tchrist They were probably conceived in working mens clubs.

Comment: Related: [What is the correct plural possessive of kids?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78476/what-s-the-correct-plural-possessive-of-kids/78483#78483).

Comment: so 'child clothing' is completely wrong?

Comment: What you "found on the internet" is the handiwork of SEO/SEM -- for the purpose of search engines, "baby" and "clothing" are the most commonly thought of words ("key words") when one thinks of clothing for infants and children. "Baby" is an excellent hypernym for infant, child, boy and girl. There's no apostrophe either because the words are searched both separately as well as together as a phrase. A web-page may have "baby" in one place and "clothing" somewhere nearby but not the exact phrase "baby's clothing" (say, "clothing for your baby"). This is less of an English language question.

Comment: OTOH, "child clothing" conjures up images of a piece of clothing that is yet to grow up, not one intended for a child. "Children's clothing/ clothes" is clear. Now that's an ELU question.

Answer (score 1):

It IS redundant to define the kind of clothing in this particular sentence. You only need to write "I went to the mall to buy clothing for my baby" and the meaning is clear. Alternatively you could have "...buy baby clothes".

In the UK, clothing stores have departments: menswear, womenswear, children’s wear, ladieswear, kidswear. There’s also children’s clothing, ladies' clothing. Note that in all of these, the person part is plural. It is wear (or clothing) for all children (or men, women, babies). There is an exception to this in "baby": for some reason baby clothes and baby wear are acceptable, and I’ve never seen a babieswear department. Wiktionary.com gives it as a rare synonym. The only reason I can give for this is the verbal sound: men, women, children all end in "n", and the "s" follows naturally. It’s slightly less natural after "baby". Alternatively, it’s because of the accepted use of "baby" as an attributive noun [An adjective or a noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147138/an-adjective-or-a-noun)

Comment: It's by no means redundant to use 'I went to buy childrens [with or without the apostrophe] clothing for my baby as we won't have the shops available where we're going for the next five years.'

Comment: My sentiments exactly.  baby clothes (the acceptable exception). And children's clothing. And I know because a family member had a store that sold children's clothing for 22 years. Yes, there is an exception for baby clothes. :) And I would not write children without an apostrophe s if followed by clothing or clothes. The entire answer applies to AmE as well. I guess the distaff side knows more about this....