# Using past participle vs existent noun form for adjective

Tags: nouns, adjectives, past-participles

There are multiple ways a noun can be described by an adjective

- by a word that is already an adjective (e.g., big, dark, high, low)
- by a noun (mushroom house)
- by a participle (running dogs, painted house)

However, I am often confused. Actually not confused, because I believe I see the picture clearer than the normal usage. Anyway, confused over the deployment of a past participle when the noun form is sufficient as the adjective:

- white-tail deer vs white-tailed deer.
- red-hair girl vs red-haired girl.
- bottle-nose dolphin vs bottle-nosed dolphin.

Because, then, why wouldn't we say

- chickened rice but chicken rice
- pepper jacked cheese but pepper jack cheese
- pepperonied pizza but pepperoni pizza
- yellow-doored house but yellow-door house
- Intel-Pentiumed PC but Intel-Pentium PC

??

The more acceptable form is bottle-nose dolphin, not bottle-nosed dolphin. Yet the more acceptable form is white-tailed deer, not white-tail deer.

How unacceptable is it to say

- red-hair girl
- white-tail deer
- bottle-nosed dolphin
- wet-backed migrant

??

Why or why not? Do provide examples of other noun vs past participle adjectives.

Comment: I think you need to check the truth of your assertions. I've just checked one that jarred with me, and I think this Ngram for [bottle-nosed dolphin v bottle-nose dolphin](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bottle-nose+dolphin%2Cbottle-nosed+dolphin&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbottle%20-%20nose%20dolphin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbottle%20-%20nosed%20dolphin%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggests that the former is more commonly used. Look up articles on participial/participle (!) adjectives, and attributive nouns, to see where they tend to be used.

Comment: This is partly covered in [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/when-can-a-noun-be-used-attributively) thread (When can a noun be used attributively?).

Comment: Edwin, should I prefer to quibble over if my examples were accurate to the bone, or should I prefer to quibble over participle vs non-participle adjectives. So please tell me why it is less desirable for me to say **yellow-doored house**? Why wouldn't more native speakers say **red-hair girl**, **white-tail deer**? Is it acceptable to say it contrary to popular practice?

Comment: It's senseless to try to start discussing why a certain usage is incorrect or less idiomatic if that's actually a false premise. // The topic is very broad, and thus probably off-topic; I'd just suggest one theory: with N M or V'd M (meals; eg chicken soup, plum pie, prawn curry ... // peppered steak, battered fish, curried prawn ...) [1] the -ed form may be unavailable (plummed?) or pretty silly-sounding (chickened?); [2] the -ed version tends to mark the noun modified as the major element of the phrase (thus steak that is battered, but not soup that is chickened).

Answer (score -1):

The examples you give have the answer. Where it is a matter of a name (e.g. of a species or product) use the noun construction: bottle-nose dolphin. When it is not, use the verb construction: red-haired girl.

Comment: What about white-tailed deer? If you don't give me a reasoned answer for white-tailed deer, I will have to vote you down. Because I feel you have but simply concocted a willy-nilly rule.