# "neophyte writer" or "neophyte in writing"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, word-usage

Quite paradoxically, I came across this usage in a blog on [How to improve your writing skills](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/how-to-improve-writing-skills/?utm_source=grammarly&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=BlogNL&utm_content=NL_061717&utm_source=&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=&utm_content=) where the author says,

> "When I was a neophyte writer..."

Is this a correct usage? Shouldn't it be

> "When I was a neophyte in writing..."

*Neophyte* is not an adjective but a noun so, it has to be a wrong usage there. But I found this on a website which I usually visit to correct my grammar and English usage, therefore, I am perplexed. Later when I googled this word, I found the same usage at few other places as well.

Can *neophyte* also be used as an adjective?

Edit: While asking this question, I was not aware of attributive nouns so didn't note this question about [usage of noun attributively](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/when-can-a-noun-be-used-attributively). But as it stands now, this can be considered a duplicate question.

Comment: I would say neophyte *at* writing, not neophyte in writing.

Comment: I don't understand why this is a duplicate question? When asked,  it was specifically on the usage of the word "neophyte"

Comment: If you read the "duplicate" question, it's talking about this English practice for _any_ noun. Neophyte is just one particular case of many – and (regarding your edit) it **is** being used attributively.

Comment: Agree, marked it duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly correct to write "neophyte writer".

### A noun can be used to modify another noun in English

This is probably an example of the noun *neophyte* being used attributively. The *[attributive noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/attributive-nouns/info)* construction (also called things like "noun adjunct" or "compound noun" or "noun used as an adjective") is common in English. You may have heard of it already; if not, you should study it. In general, any noun can be placed before any other noun to modify it (the exact meaning of this construction is fairly vague).

A comparable example would be "master writer", which is acceptable even though "master" is not an adjective.

### In addition, nouns can often be converted to adjectives

That said, it is fairly easy to convert a noun (or substantive) to an true adjective or vice versa in English. It would not be too surprising to me to see *neophyte* used as a true adjective, and in fact the Oxford English Dictionary classifies it as possibly being an adjective:

> B. adj. (chiefly attrib.).
>
> Recently converted, initiated, or ordained; inexperienced. Also: characteristic of a recent convert or of a beginner or novice; displaying inexperience.

The most adjective-like example listed in the OED in my opinion is

- > 1883   R. L. Stevenson *Silverado Squatters* i. iii. 44   A certain neophite and girlish trepidation.

  (the word "neophyte" is here coordinated with the word "girlish", which is unambiguously an adjective)

I think one factor that may faciliate this conversion is the etymology of the term: *neophyte* is borrowed from Ancient Greek, via Latin, and both of these languages generally have easy interchange of substantives and adjectives. In Latin, *[neophytus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=neophytus)* was perfectly acceptable as an adjective; it was borrowed from a Greek word meaning "newly planted".

Comment: One of those questions where a close-vote is really required (I've gone for 'duplicate' based on the statement 'Neophyte is not an adjective but a noun so, it has to be a wrong usage there'; lack of research is perhaps more defensible) but the answer contains a good treatment of particulars. I can't be bothered looking for the previous 'attributive ---> adjectival conversion' discussion; it might have included 'more fun vs funner'.