# Conjuring is listed as a noun on Google and Longman but then why does it appear as an adjective in the examples listed at these places?

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives, dictionaries, errors

E.g., on Google, the meaning is: "the performance of tricks which are seemingly magical, typically involving sleight of hand." But the given example is: "a conjuring trick". Similarly, the example in LDOCE is: "He did conjuring tricks for the children." Why does it appear as an adjective in the dictionaries when it is listed as a noun?

Comment: I think the first sentence in [a related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/when-can-a-noun-be-used-attributively) might answer this one.

Comment: There will be disputes about what part of speech "conjuring" is, but it could arguably be considered a participle modifying a noun. http://myenglishgrammar.com/lesson-12-modifiers/5-participles-as-modifiers.html

Comment: Dictionaries are not authoritative about parts of speech. They can give examples, but they do not have reliable grammatical information.