# Conversation skills vs Conversational skills

Tags: differences

I'm trying to write a sentence like this -

"Our classes have enabled children to enhance their reading, writing and conversational skills."

Is this correct? Or it supposed to be conversation skills? I feel both are correct. Is there any difference in the meaning conveyed either way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When can a noun be used attributively? When is this usage preferred over the corresponding adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/when-can-a-noun-be-used-attributively)

Answer (score 0):

No difference in substance. “Conversational” is more common. A real adjective, if it exists, is generally preferred over a noun-turned-adjective.

Comment: A pity you don't add supporting evidence. Your statement about which is the more common here is nicely backed up by Google ngrams. Adding support to your more general statement will need quite a lot of research, but would give the sort of answer valued on ELU. Although it may have been covered here before; I'll check for duplicates later.